# Is it possible to display the commands being executed when running a .sh script in the terminal

Tags: python, linux, bash, terminal

I have an executable bash file with commands.

It appears these files do not show what is being executed as the lines get executed by the terminal.

Is there a way to show the lines that are being executed?

Comment: @Dummy Code, you mean like write them twice ? one for execution and one for echo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use bash's debugging option, `bash -x HelloWorld.sh` **or** `#!/bin/bash -x`

This will produce the following output...

```
+ echo 'Hello, World!'
Hello, World!
```

See more [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html)

Comment: Try also the `-v` flag. I often find it more convenient than `-x`. You can combine them, but that's usually overkill.

Comment: @tripleee I don't like that it prints everything rather than just the commands.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to add `set -x` to the script where you would like execution to begin debugging. You can also use `set +x` to stop.

Example:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -x
echo "This will be debugged"
set +x
echo "This will not be debugged"
```